# Select a random entry from a dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, random

I have the following python dictionary:

```
    truthDict = {
     1: False,
    -1: True,
     3: True,
    -3: False,
    -4: False,
     4: True,
     2: True,
    -2: True,
     5: False,
    -5: True
    }
```

I would like to flip one of the key to the inverse:

I tried this:

```py
    pick = random.choice(truthDict.keys())  
    truthDict[pick] = not(truthDict[pick])
```

However it does not work, I would really appreciate any help.

Comment: what is expected output ?

Comment: Isn’t this just bog-standard dictionary access? You couldn’t find any resources to learn how to do this? What does _it does not work_ mean? Also, variable and function names should follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style.

Answer (score 3):

You were pretty close, `dict_keys` does not support indexing, so pass a list which does:

```
pick = random.choice([*truthDict])
truthDict[pick] = not truthDict[pick]
```

Comment: is there any difference/advantage to `[*truthDict]` opposed to `list(truthDict)`?

Comment: @MarkMeyer The only difference is `list(truthDict)` works for every python version currently in production. Edit: actually that's not accurate, the iterable unpacking syntax is a bit faster than the `list()` function call.

Comment: @cs95 Unpacking should be much slower as the input grows though, no?

Comment: @AlexanderCécile unpacking is a bit faster for me with dicts at least up to 10 million keys.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `list()` around `truthDict.keys()`

```py
pick = random.choice(list(truthDict.keys()))
truthDict[pick]  = not(truthDict[pick])
```

> time: ~5.72 µs

---

or unpack using `*`

```py
pick = random.choice([*(truthDict.keys())])
truthDict[pick]  = not(truthDict[pick])
```

> time: ~4.53 µs

Comment: yes, it's not working I forgot to add `[` `]`, editing the answer